# couchdb how to disable httpd leaving only httpsd working?

Tags: https, couchdb

I enabled httpsd but how to disable the httpd, leaving only httpsd working?

/etc/couchdb/local.ini

...
        [daemons]
        ; enable SSL support by uncommenting the following line and supply        the PEM's below.
        ; the default ssl port CouchDB listens on is 6984
         httpsd = {couch_httpd, start_link, [https]}

```
    [ssl]
    cert_file =        /servidor_html/hipso/acesso_seguro/certificados_ssl/hipso_eu.crt
    key_file = /servidor_html/hipso/acesso_seguro/certificados_ssl/hipso_eu.key
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d set the `bind_address` in the `[httpd]` section to `127.0.0.1`, so no external access is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems it's not possible at the moment. Apparently it has been possible in a [past version](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48203146#HowDoIConfigureSSL(HTTPS)inCouchDB?-DisablingCouchDBHTTPlayer) and there is a [github issue](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/2106) opened for this feature.

One way to achieve the same effect is to use firewall to drop the incoming request, e.g. using [ufw](https://code.launchpad.net/ufw): `ufw deny 5984`